# cookie.setMaxAge strange behaviour

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, cookies

I work in a jsp based website that needs cookies enabled in order to navigate it (It is an internal site, it will not be exposed to the internet).

The first visit of a user will return a 302 to the same url that was requested, and set a cookie for an hour.

I am using `Cookie.setMaxAge(60*60);` to set the expiry date.

I am having a really weird behaviour with some versions of some browsers where they keep redirecting forever. (Some work, some don't work).

After a lot of investigation, we've discovered that the time in the server is not set to the correct time, and it has its time set to two hours and a half in the past, rsulting on that the cookie may "expired" as it is set. (here's my doubt)

Unfortunately this is a production server and I cannot change it easily (it's being requested but it will take some time).

Just to confirm this was the issue, I changed the time of a client machine to two hours and a half in the past and it started to work fine in that machine.

My questions are :

1. what information is sent to the browser (regarding cookie expiry
   date), it is an absolute date or is it relative to the current
   time?.
2. does the browser send cookies if they are expired along with
   the expiry date or the browser just don't send them if they are
   expired?    ( I think is the second option).
3. as I had trouble with some browser and it worked with others, dont' know exactly here's
   the problem, in the appserver or in the browser?

**[EDIT]**

After reading RFC 6265 as Arham suggest, the expiry date can be set by the server as absolute or relative. In case both are presenr, relative takes precedence. 
The appserver I am using is setting the cookie with the absolute value (which is probably wrong), so I don't understand how it is working on some browsers.

**[/EDIT]**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As per RFC 1123, the date is specified in the form of “Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT”.
2. As per RFC 6265, the cookie’s expiration is relative to the time the browser received the cookie.
3. Browser deletes the cookie once it's expired, hence it cant send the same cookie to the server.

Comment: 1) and 2) seems to be opposed. I'd understand that the date is absolute from 1) and relative from 2). Right?

Comment: By 2nd point, I meant that the age of the cookie or expiration time is set relative to the time when the browser received the cookie. It has nothing to do with the Date.

Answer (score 1):

How about javascript cookies?

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: thanks for the response. The solution is going to be to adjust the server time. I just had curiosity on which component was doing it wrong.